# Are Linkage Distance, Within groups sum of squares and Minimum Distance within clusters different

Tags: classification, clustering

I am doing a cluster analysis and confused with three terms. Are Linkage Distance, Within groups sum of squares (total within sum of square), and Minimum Distance within clusters different when you do Hierarchical average-linkage.

Comment: They are. But I fail to see what you mean by *linkage distance*. Where did you see this in the software you might be using?

Answer (score 0):

Linkage distance depends on which linkage you are using.

You can be clustering with minimum linkage (single link), maximum, least squares (ward), or a few others.